# Setting colors using color cycle on date plots using `plot_date()`

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to plot multiple date graphs using matplotlibs `plot_date` function. One thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to assign each graph a different color automatically (as happens with `plot` after setting `axes.color_cycle` in `matplotlib.rcParams`). Example code:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

values = xrange(1, 13)
dates = [dt.datetime(2013, i, 1, i, 0, 0, 0) for i in values]
mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['r', 'g']
for i in (0, 1, 2):
    nv = map(lambda k: k+i, values)
    d = mdates.date2num(dates)
    plt.plot_date(d, nv, ls="solid")
plt.show()
```

This gives me a nice figure with 3 lines in them but they all have the same color. Changing the call to `plot_date` to just `plot` results in 3 lines in red and green but unfortunately the labels on the x axis are not useful anymore.

So my question is, is there any way to get the coloring to work with `plot_date` similarly easy as it does for just `plot`?

Comment: I also found out that it just works with `plot()`, this is probably a bug...

Comment: opened [an issue in GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2148) for this problem...

Comment: @sgpc This isn't a bug, but a design choice.  There is a default argument in both `plt.date_plot` and `axes.date_plot` that sets the format to `bo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this discussion in `GitHub`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2148) it came out a good way to solve this issue:

```
ax.plot_date(d, nv, ls='solid', fmt='')
```

as @tcaswell explained, this function set `fmt='bo'` by default, and the user can overwrite this by passing the argument `fmt` when calling `plot_date()`.

Doing this, the result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Despite the possible bug you've found you can workaround that and create the plot like this:

[image]

The code is as follows. Basically a `plot()` is added just after the `plot_date()`:

```
values = xrange(1, 13)
dates = [dt.datetime(2013, i, 1, i, 0, 0, 0) for i in values]
mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['r', 'g', 'r']
ax = plt.subplot(111)
for i in (0, 1, 2):
    nv = map(lambda k: k+i, values)
    d = mdates.date2num(dates)
    ax.plot_date(d, nv, ls='solid')
    ax.plot(d, nv, '-o')
plt.gcf().tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Note that another `'r'` was required because, despite not showing, the colors are indeed cycling in `plot_date()`, and without this the lines would be green-red-green.

Comment: This is super hacky.  You are over plotting identical data and just using the `plot_date` calls to set the formatters.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug, but a design choice.  There is a default argument in both `plt.date_plot` and `axes.date_plot` that sets the format to `bo`.

See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes.py#L4145 and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L2997

[left same comment on github]

The only thing that `plot_date` does for you over `plot` is some configuration of the axes formatters, which you can do by hand.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


values = xrange(1, 13)
dates = [dt.datetime(2013, i, 1, i, 0, 0, 0) for i in values]
mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['r', 'g', 'r']
ax = plt.subplot(111)
for i in (0, 1, 2):
    nv = map(lambda k: k+i, values)
    d = mdates.date2num(dates)

    ax.plot(d, nv, '-o')

ax.xaxis_date()
plt.gcf().tight_layout()
plt.show()
```